# Got an error reading communication packets on writer instance only

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora

So I am connecting with aurora MySQL 5.7.12-log with Django. Below (1) is the query auto-generated by Django when I hit runserver.

1. `` SELECT `django_migrations`.`app`, `django_migrations`.`name` FROM `django_migrations`; ``
2. . `SELECT django_migrations.app, django_migrations.name FROM django_migrations;`

The difference is the backtick only.

Query 1 (on mysql shell) gives me an error `2019-03-06T10:41:11.390834Z 13660 [Note] Aborted connection 13660 to db: '<db>' user: '<user>' host: '<host>' (Got an error reading communication packets)`. So I run query 2 and it runs fine.

More weirdly, the same query runs on reader instance and cluster reader instance but not on the writer instance. Also, If I reboot the db the issue won't occur for a while but will start occurring after the db keeps running for a day or so.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on and how to fix it?

**Edit**

adding some more info:

`` mysql> SELECT `django_migrations`.`app`, `django_migrations`.`name` FROM `django_migrations`;
Empty set, 25856 warnings (0.04 sec) ``

show i run `show warnings;`

And the warnings are all the same: `Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead`.

Comment: Well, that's a strange one!

Comment: I'd test if it is a 5.7.12 bug by dumping the same table and loading it into a newer MySQL-5.7 version.

Comment: This is on aurora. I think this is the only version they are providing. I haven't faced this problem with non-aurora mysql as far as I can think. have raised an issue with them.